# can't get memcache value in dev console memcache viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I am setting cache properly as my project does grab the correct result from it. I want to view it in the **dev console** memcache viewer (http://localhost:8080/_ah/amdin/memcache) 
But when I paste in the key, it says "no such key". The memcache statement I use is:

```
stuff=memcache.get(userid, namespace='book')
```

So when I use the userid (aka key) in the memcache viewer, it fails. Am I to somehow add the namespace? I tried that and that failed. I also tried the entity key, that was a fail. any ideas?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can't retrieve a namespaced memcache key using the dev console memcache viewer.

You have more than an option though:

a. Use the interactive console with a code like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache  
print memcache.get(youruserid, namespace='book')
```

b. Create an admin section (Webapp+memcache api) to your web application adding this feature